# Laravel: How can I show error message using query builder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update a row on my table with this query builder.

```
$new_item = DB::table('peminjams')
            ->where('id', $dipinjam->id_peminjam)
            ->update([
                 'nama' => $request->nama,
                 'cp' => $request->cp,
                 'jaminan' => $request->jaminan
             ]);
```

when I `dd($new_item)` it return false, the item did not update.

I still don't know why it failed since its only gives an boolean value.

Comment: try to debug your code. first check `->where('id', $dipinjam->id_peminjam)->first()` whether it returns any value. then check the request values.

Comment: try dd($dipinjam->id_peminjam) can this return any value or not

Comment: Make sure those attributes of your model are not in `$guarded` property, because if they are, they won't be mass [assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment). Or if you're using `$fillable` instead, make sure those attributes are in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        // Validate the value...
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $exception->getMessage();exit;

    }
```

OR

```
if ($exception instanceof \HttpException || $exception instanceof \ErrorException) {

                $exceptionArry = [
                    'file'    => $exception->getFile(),
                    'code'    => $exception->getCode(),
                    'line'    => $exception->getLine(),
                    'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                ];
                dd($exceptionArry);
            }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

Answer (score 1):

First, we check `first()` method to returns value. if return value is null it will return false.

```
$new_item = DB::table('peminjams')->where('id', $dipinjam->id_peminjam)->first();

if(is_null($new_item)) {
    return false;
} else {
    DB::table('peminjams')
        ->where('id', $dipinjam->id_peminjam)
        ->update([
            'nama' => $request->nama,
            'cp' => $request->cp,
            'jaminan' => $request->jaminan
        ]);
}
```

##### using eloquent

```
$new_item = Peminjams::findOrFail($dipinjam->id_peminjam);

$new_item->nama = $request->nama;
$new_item->cp = $request->cp;
$new_item->jaminan = $request->jaminan;
$new_item->update();
```